# Usar distinct em row

Tags: php, sql

Bom pessoal estou com uma duvida, estou tentando retornar do bd somente os estados que possuem o termo pesquisado porem nao quero repetilos. segue o codigo

```
<?php
$search_term = filter_var($_GET["s"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$q = "SELECT DISTINCT estado FROM classificados WHERE texto LIKE '%".$search_term."%'  ";
$r = mysql_query($q);
if(mysql_num_rows($r)==0)// se nao encontrar resultado
{
echo "--";
}
else //se encontrar algum resultado
{ echo " <option value='index.php?s=$search_term&e=$estado'> $estado </option>" ;} ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Boa tarde. Pelo que estou vendo sua consulta está correta. Está dando algum erro ou coisa parecida?

Comment: Mas eu acho que seu problema não é com o **distinct**. Ele imprime o '**--**'? Pelo que estou vendo o erro está no else, creio que você teria que fazer um loop e imprimir os resultados e não da forma que você está fazendo ai. Só não respondo pq não sou safo em PHP.

Comment: Parece que está faltando um `mysql_fetch_assoc()` antes do echo do option. `$estado` foi definida onde?

Comment: logo no inicio do codigo depois da conexao

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como apontado pelo Edgar, você precisa iterar os registros retornados para isso use a função `mysql_fetch_assoc()`

```
}else{
   while($linha = mysql_fetch_assoc($r){
      echo "<option value='index.php?s=$search_term&e=$linha['estado']>
               $linha['estado']
            </option>";
   }
}
?>
</select>
```

Comment: realmente era isso mesmo, tava desatendo vleu pela ajuda